# Func2, times, y, rho error

Tags: r, model, ode

I keep getting the error:

```
Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) : 
  The number of derivatives returned by func() (175) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (51)
```

I am trying to create a model based off of Brigatti et al 2009 (pred-prey model w a spatial component)

```
x<-c(1:40000)

left_shift = function(x) {
  x[c(2:length(x), 1)]
}

right_shift = function(x) {
  x[c(length(x), 1:(length(x) - 1))]
}

laplace = function(x) {
  return(c(left_shift(x) + right_shift(x) - 2 * x))
}

dxdt <- function(time, state, pars) {
  prey = state[1:length(state) / 2]
  pred = state[(length(state) / 2 + 1):length(state)]
  dprey = pars[5] * laplace(prey) + pars[1] * prey - x[2] * prey * pred
  dpred = pars[5] * laplace(pred) + pars[3] * prey * pred - pars[4] *  pred
  list(c(prey, pred, dprey, dpred))
}

time <- seq(0, 600, by = 1)
pars <- c(alpha=1, 
      beta = .5, 
      gamma = .2, 
      delta = .6,
      D = 0.000008 #(0.004*0.004/2), #diffusion coefficient
        )

state <- rep(0.1, 51)

out <- as.data.frame(ode(func = dxdt, y = state, parms = pars, times =  time))
```

Comment: Your `state` parameter has a length of 51, but your function `dxdt` gives 175 values back. Do you have a link to your model where we can see equations?

Comment: This is all the code that I have for the model but I am basing it off equations from Bertelli et all 2009 Pattern formation in a predator-prey system characterized by a spatial scale of interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems. First, missing parentheses.

```
prey = state[1:length(state) / 2]
```

should read

```
prey = state[1:(length(state) / 2)]
```

Second, your initial conditions are an odd number in length. `state` should specify the initial conditions for both prey **and** predator (in that order). So, for each location there should be two values and, consequently, the vector should always be a multiple of two in length.

Thirdly, your function `dxdt` should return `list(c(dprey, dpred))`. There is no reason to return the values for the state variables, because the ODE solver will calculate those.

Fix those and this is what you get:

```
left_shift = function(x) {
  x[c(2:length(x), 1)]
}

right_shift = function(x) {
  x[c(length(x), 1:(length(x) - 1))]
}

laplace = function(x) {
  return(c(left_shift(x) + right_shift(x) - 2 * x))
}

dxdt <- function(time, state, pars) {
  prey = state[1:(length(state) / 2)]
  pred = state[(length(state) / 2 + 1):length(state)]
  dprey = pars[5] * laplace(prey) + pars[1] * prey - x[2] * prey * pred
  dpred = pars[5] * laplace(pred) + pars[3] * prey * pred - pars[4] *  pred

  list(c(dprey, dpred))
}

time <- seq(0, 600, by = 1)
pars <- c(alpha=1, 
          beta = .5, 
          gamma = .2, 
          delta = .6,
          D = 0.000008 #(0.004*0.004/2), #diffusion coefficient
)

state <- rep(0.1, 50)

out <- as.data.frame(ode(func = dxdt, y = state, parms = pars, times =  time))
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are a lifesaver!! Truly thanks again :)